# Failed to append sample buffer: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 (OSStatus error -12763.)

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I'm working on a live video, I just program the video picker and send to the server. I use `AVCaptureSession` to get the audio and video, then use `AVAssetWriter` write to many mp4 file. When I use `[writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]` to append buffer, it can work but sometimes I get an error.

> [com.ifactorylab.ifassetencoder.encodingqueue] Failed to append sample buffer: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x1314e08b0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x173259ad0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12763.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12763), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

And then the memory for sampleBuffer will be full, and the capture delegate stops. Someone said `finishWritingWithCompletionHandler` would not work then. It's the description of -12763,-12763 @constant   kCMBufferQueueError_EnqueueAfterEndOfData CMBufferQueueEnqueue was attempted after CMBufferQueueMarkEndOfData was called (without a call to CMBufferQueueReset in between).

I don't know how it happens, and how to avoid it or what I did to make it happen.

Here is my main code

```
- (void)encodeSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer ofType:(IFCapturedBufferType)mediaType {
if (assetEncodingQueue_) {
    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
    // We'd like encoding job running asynchronously
    dispatch_async(assetEncodingQueue_, ^{
        int writtenBufferCount = 0;
        if (pendingSampleBuffers_.count > 0) {
            for (KSYPendingSampleBuffer *pending in pendingSampleBuffers_) {
                CMSampleBufferRef buf = [pending getSampleBuffer];
                if (![self writeSampleBuffer:buf ofType:pending.mediaType]) {
                    break;
                }
                writtenBufferCount++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < writtenBufferCount; ++i) {
                [pendingSampleBuffers_ removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            }
        }
        // Write the given sample buffer to output file through AVAssetWriter
        if (pendingSampleBuffers_.count > 0 || ![self writeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:mediaType]) {
                [pendingSampleBuffers_ addObject:
                 [KSYPendingSampleBuffer pendingSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:mediaType]];
                DDLogDebug(@"pendingSampleBuffers_.count = %@",@(pendingSampleBuffers_.count));
        }

        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    });
}
else {
    DDLogDebug(@"No valid assetEncodingQueue_ exist");
}
}


- (BOOL)writeSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer ofType:(IFCapturedBufferType)mediaType {
//    DDLogDebug(@"Even if stream is coming, just do nothing if we are not ready yet.");
if (self.encoderState != kEncoderStateRunning) {
    DDLogDebug(@"stated =%d",self.encoderState);
    return NO;
}
[assetMetaWriter error]);

if ([self encodeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:mediaType assetWriter:assetWriter]) {
    if (!watchOutputFileReady_) {
        [self watchOutputFile:[outputURL path]];
    }
}
else {
    DDLogDebug(@"*************** Failed to encode given sample buffer");
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

- (BOOL)encodeSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
                ofType:(IFCapturedBufferType)mediaType
           assetWriter:(AVAssetWriter *)writer {
if (!CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer)) {
    DDLogDebug(@"SampleBufferDataIsReady?? no");
    return NO;
}
if (writer.status == AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown) {
    if ([writer startWriting]) {
        @try {
            CMTime startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
            [writer startSessionAtSourceTime:startTime];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            DDLogDebug(@"Couldn't add audio(2)/video(1)--%d input: %@",mediaType, [exception description]);
            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        DDLogDebug(@"Failed to start writing(%@): %@", writer.outputURL,
              [writer error]);
        return NO;
    }
}
if (writer.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {
    if (mediaType == kBufferVideo) {
        return [self appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer toWriterInput:self.videoEncoder.assetWriterInput];
    } else if (mediaType == kBufferAudio) {
        return [self appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer toWriterInput:self.audioEncoder.assetWriterInput];
    }
}
return NO;
}


- (BOOL)appendSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
         toWriterInput:(AVAssetWriterInput *)writerInput {
if (writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
    @try {
        if (!**[writerInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]**) {
            DDLogDebug(@"Failed to append sample buffer: %@", [assetWriter error]);
            [writerInput markAsFinished];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DDLogDebug(@"Couldn't append sample buffer: %@", [exception description]);
        return NO;
    }
}else {
    DDLogDebug(@"writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData = no");
}
return NO;
}

- (void)watchOutputFile:(NSString *)filePath {
dispatch_queue_t queue =
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
double movieBitrate = self.videoEncoder.bitRate + self.audioEncoder.bitRate;
self.outputFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
dispatchSource_ = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE,
                                         [outputFileHandle fileDescriptor],
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE |
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE |
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND |
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_ATTRIB |
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_LINK |
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_RENAME |
                                         DISPATCH_VNODE_REVOKE,
                                         queue);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(dispatchSource_, ^{
    unsigned long flags = dispatch_source_get_data(dispatchSource_);
    if (flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_DELETE) {
        dispatch_source_cancel(dispatchSource_);
        dispatchSource_ = nil;
    }

    // When file size has changed,
    if (flags & DISPATCH_VNODE_EXTEND) {

        NSData *chunk = [outputFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
        if ([chunk length] > (movieBitrate / 10)) {
            if (assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {
                if (self.encoderState != kEncoderStateRunning) {
                    DDLogDebug(@"encoderState =%d",encoderState_);
                    return;
                }

                @try {
                    // Update current encoder status to "EncoderFinishing"
                    self.encoderState = kEncoderStateFinishing;
                    DDLogDebug(@"检测到一波写入结束，设为kEncoderStateFinishing");
                    // Regardless of job failure, we need to reset current encoder
                    dispatch_source_cancel(dispatchSource_);
                    dispatchSource_ = nil;

                    [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
                        // Meanwhile finishing, if we received stop signal, don't restart
                        // asset encoder again.
                        DDLogDebug(@"finishWritingWithCompletionHandler");
                        BOOL restartEncoder = YES;
                        if (self.encoderState == kEncoderStateStopped) {
                            DDLogDebug(@"self.encoderState == kEncoderStateStopped");
                            restartEncoder = NO;
                        }

                        if (assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed) {
                            DDLogDebug(@"Failed to finish writing: %@", [assetWriter error]);
                        } else {
                            NSData *movWithMoov =
                            [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:assetWriter.outputURL.path];

                            NSArray *frames = nil;
                            KSYMP4Reader *mp4Reader = [[KSYMP4Reader alloc] init];

                            if ([movWithMoov length] > 0) {
                                // Let's parse mp4 header
                                [mp4Reader readData:[KSYBytesData dataWithNSData:movWithMoov]];
                                frames = [mp4Reader readFrames];

                                // double pts = [self getOldestPts];

                                if (!readMovieMeta_ && metaHeaderHandler) {
                                    readMovieMeta_ = YES;
                                    metaHeaderHandler(mp4Reader);
                                }
                            }

                            if (captureHandler) {
                                captureHandler(frames, movWithMoov);
                            }

                            assetWriter = nil;
                        }

                        if (restartEncoder) {
                            // Once it's done, generate new file name and reinitiate AVAssetWrite
                            self.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self getOutputFilePath:fileType]
                                                        isDirectory:NO];

                            NSError *error;
                            assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputURL
                                                                    fileType:fileType
                                                                       error:&error];

                            // setVideoEncoder and setAudioEncoder will retain the given
                            // encoder objects so we need to reduce reference as it's retained
                            // in the functions.
                            [assetWriter addInput:self.videoEncoder.assetWriterInput];
                            [assetWriter addInput:self.audioEncoder.assetWriterInput];

                            self.encoderState = kEncoderStateRunning;
                            DDLogDebug(@"新的一波设为kEncoderStateRunning");
                            // we are good to go.
                            @synchronized (self) {
                                watchOutputFileReady_ = NO;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Update current encoder status to "EncoderFinished", if we
                            // don't start the encoder again.
                            self.encoderState = kEncoderStateFinished;
                        }
                    }];
                } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    DDLogDebug(@"Caught exception: %@", [exception description]);
                    self.encoderState = kEncoderStateFinished;
                }
            }
        } else {
            [outputFileHandle seekToFileOffset:0];
        }
    }
});

dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(dispatchSource_, ^(void){
    [outputFileHandle closeFile];
});

dispatch_resume(dispatchSource_);
watchOutputFileReady_ = YES;
}
```